# SQL Adding extra rows until dates (YYYYMMDD) columns match

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, while-loop, common-table-expression

Table1:

```
ID|StartDateID|EndDateID 
468|20200101|20200104
534|20200103|20200104
123|20200106|20200108
```

Required output:

```
ID|StartDateID|EndDateID 
468|20200101|20200104
468|20200102|20200104
468|20200103|20200104
468|20200104|20200104
534|20200103|20200104
534|20200104|20200104
123|20200106|20200108
123|20200107|20200108
123|20200108|20200108
```

Apologies if this is poorly explained. Table1 lists the start and end dates of a task completion. Each ID is an unique entry.

I need an extra row for each StartDateID (adding 1 each time), until it matches EndDate.

A day is added to StartDateID until it matches EndDateID, at which point we stop replication.

Does that make sense?

I've played around with CTE, but got nowhere.

Comment: What is the data type of the columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a recursive CTE.  Assuming that the columns are actually dates:

```
with cte as (
      select ID, StartDateID, EndDateID 
      from t
      union all
      select id, dateadd(day, 1, startdateid), enddateid
      from cte
      where startdateid < enddateid
     )
select *
from cte;
```

If the columns are not dates, I would advise converting them:

```
with cte as (
      select ID, convert(date, StartDateID) as startdate, convert(date, EndDateID) as enddate
      from t
      union all
      select id, dateadd(day, 1, startdate), enddate
      from cte
      where startdate < enddate
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3d6c1d048fb04b7eb51526f339d08d7d) is a db<>fiddle.

If your spans can exceed 100 days, then you need to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` to the query.